# Syntax error on Windows and not on Linux

Tags: php

The following code is giving me errors when run on windows with php version 5.3.5:

```
$dir_widgets = '/var/www/site-sp/dir1/filename.json';
```

error here:

```
$folder_name = array_reverse( explode( '/' , $dir_widgets ) )[ 1 ];
```

This is the error reported:

```
*Parse error*: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
```

On GNU/Ubuntu 13.04 with PHP version 5.4.9 it works fine.

Can be the PHP version? Is it bad practice to do the following?

```
array_reverse( explode( '/' , $dir_widgets ) )[ 1 ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: **Tell us what error it gives you** and also why don't you use [**`json_decode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) instead and read the object? Keep in mind that on windows `/var/www/site-sp/dir1/filename.json` is not a valid directory path.

Comment: Are the directory path's exactly the same? That directory path is typical for a linux install of PHP, not Windows.

Comment: Windows uses a totally different directory structure, so
`/var/www/site-sp/dir1/filename.json` makes no sense on a windows machine, it should be something like `c:\\blah\\www\\site-sp\\dir1\\filename.json`

Comment: Yes,I forgot set the dir on windows: is like c:\blah\www\site-sp\dir1\filename.json. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accessing an array index directly from a return value was added in PHP 5.4 hence why you are getting a syntax error with version 5.3. You'll need to save the return value from the function to a temporary variable and then access the index you want.

Something like:

```
$tmp_array = array_reverse( explode( '/' , $dir_widgets ) );
$tmp_array[1] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.3 won't let you reference a value in an array as you are trying to do.

You need to set the return from `array_reverse()` to a variable and the reference the element from that variable a la `$var = array_reverse(); $var[1];`